# asp.net textarea title should display the content of textbox

Tags: c#, html, textarea, title

Is there a way to define attribute of textarea title='this.value' so that what change made on value of text area will reflect on tooltip.

My requirement is to show the entire content of textarea as tooltip since the page holds large number of text areas and size of text area is too small. so instead of scrolling they want to see complete text as tooltip on hovering on top of the text area.

Comment: Twitter bootstrap has what you are looking for.I would use a pop-over for this: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-examples

Comment: Thanks. Here i didn't see an option to display the content as tooltip or to dynamically change the tooltip content on textchange.

Comment: can anyone please help? any jquery plugin that will display the text box content as tooltip